# Postgres Nested Query for a single table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am stuck on a nested database query. Can I get some help?

My simple table looks like this:

food_table:

```
+----+----------+-------------------------------+
| ID | NAME     | Nutrient      | NutrientAmount
+----+----------+---------------+---------------+
        food1       calcium            200
        food1       magnesium          300
        food1       phosphorus         400
        food2       calcium            220
        food2       magnesium          320
        food2       phosphorus         430
        food3       calcium            230
         .............
```

I want to select top 15 foods that have the most calcium and magnesium. It doesn't matter calcium or magnesium has the most.

I tried to use `order by`, but it doesn't work because it is to order a column. The data that I want to sort is stored in different rows.

I am new to database design. If schema has problem, I am am to change the schema also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky.  You can do this using `GROUP BY` as:

```
select name
from food_table
where Nutrient in ('calcium', 'magnesium' )
group by name
order by max(NutrientAmount) desc 
limit 15;
```

If you wanted to consider *both* nutrients together, you would use `sum()` rather than `max()`.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to get the whole row rather than name? I tried to another select, but the order is lost.

Comment: @kevinzf . . . That is actually trickier than it seems.  I would suggest that you ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using distinct

```
select distinct NAME
from food_table
where Nutrient in ('calcium', 'magnesium' )
order by NutrientAmount DESC 
LIMIT 15
```

or for avoid distinct limit issue you can try using

```
select distinct t.name 
from (
    select NAME
    from food_table
    where Nutrient in ('calcium', 'magnesium' )
    order by NutrientAmount DESC 
) t
LIMIT 15
```

Comment: Thanks. I got an error: [42P10] ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list                                                                      
My query is: select distinct recipe_title
from recipe
where nutrient_id in (1, 2,3) order by nutrient_amount DESC
LIMIT 15